# Google Cloud Platform, AI & Machine Learning Products, Getting started: Training and Prediction with TensorFlow Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, gcloud, prediction

i try to complete test from Training and prediction with TensorFlow Estimator.
My current step is "Submit a batch prediction job" (https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs/getting-started-tensorflow-estimator#submit_a_batch_prediction_job).
Command is

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit prediction $JOB_NAME \
--model $MODEL_NAME \
--version v1 \
--data-format text \
--region $REGION \
--input-paths $TEST_JSON \
--output-path $OUTPUT_PATH/predictions
```

All variables have value now. But $TEST_JSON dont have.

```
JOB_NAME=census_prediction_1
MODEL_NAME=census
REGION=europe-west1
OUTPUT_PATH=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$JOB_NAME
```

It is --input-path.
I tried use

```
TEST_JSON=../test.json
```

but there is error:
ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.jobs.submit.prediction) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Field: input_paths Error: The provided GCS paths [../test.json] cannot be read. Please make sure that the objects exist and you have read access to it.
If i check

```
cat $TEST_JSON
```

file ../test.json opening OK.
I dont understand where is mistake.

Comment: can you accept and up vote the answer pls :-)

Answer (score 2):

The input path is meant to be a GCS bucket
Set the variable in the manner below;

TEST_JSON=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/data/test.json

From your description it seems you are using test.json, locally stored;

It is --input-path. I tried use

TEST_JSON=../test.json

> From the doc [gcloud ai-platform jobs submit prediction](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/prediction?hl=es-419);
>
> --input-paths=INPUT_PATH,[INPUT_PATH,…] Google Cloud Storage paths to the instances to run prediction on. Wildcards (*) accepted at the end
>   of a path. More than one path can be specified if multiple file
>   patterns are needed. For example, 
>   gs://my-bucket/instances*,gs://my-bucket/other-instances1